Shrinkage That Does not Preserve Partial Order
When estimating multivariate means, do all shrinkage approaches preserve partial order? I mean do the order of the means from a MLE estimate change after shrinkage?
Clearly the shrinkages in the form $\hat{m}' = (1-\lambda)\hat{m}$ are order preserving (assured that $\lambda$ is between 0 and 1).
Are there any approaches to shrinkage that doesn't preserve partial order (basically making them equal after shrinkage doesn't count, such as hard thresholding).
Obviously one may put an arbitrary prior somewhere that will achieve this. But I am asking more towards an empirical Bayesian setting.

I'm not following your distinction between order and partial order. Could you please clarify?

@Dave after shrinkage if they are equal, for example hard thresholding makes some coefficients 0, that is a scenario I am not interested in. I am looking for a case where pre shrinkage if a > b, after shrinkage b > a strictly (without equality).

I think the most relevant way in which the value of coefficients changes due to regularization, is that the likelihood “improvements” are dependent on other coefficients being large.
In the context of linear models this happens when explanatory variables are correlated, creating inverse correlation between the coefficient-estimates.  In the following example I simulate $x_2$ and $x_3$ with negative correlation, which then means their coefficient-estimates have positive correlation. The coefficients are positive, i.e. one “growing” also grows the other. This then causes them to be doubly effected by the Ridge-regression penalty term, $\lambda\Vert \vec\beta\Vert_2^2$ of course being equivalent to an iid normal prior.
As result the smallest coefficient ($x_1$) in the unregularized model ends up the largest at $\log(\lambda) = 1$.
library(glmnet)
set.seed("2")
n <- 400
x1 <- scale(rnorm(n))
x2 <- scale(rnorm(n))
x3 <- scale(rnorm(n) - x2)

y <- 0.8*x1 + 1.5*x2 + x3 + rnorm(n)
mod_ml <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)
summary(mod_ml)
mod <- glmnet(cbind(x1, x2, x3), y, alpha = 0)

plot(mod, xvar = "lambda", xlim = c(-3, 1), ylim = c(0, 1.7), col = c(1,2,4))
legend("topright", legend = paste0("x", 1:3, ", the point being unregularied"), col = c(1,2,4), lty = 1, pch = 1)
points(x= rep(-3, 3), y = coef(mod_ml)[2:4], col = c(1,2,4))

# take a look at variance covariance matrox if the model coefficinet estiamtes
vcov(mod_ml)


Too more threads about how different variables can depend on each other for their coefficient in linear models. The likelihhod being equivalent to $R^2$ in that context:

A good explanation by me: How can delta (Δ) R² for a term be larger than R² for that term?
Ben linking to his Arxiv-paper that really breaks this down, but is a little unapproachable: Should individual $R^2$ of a predictor always be greater than $\Delta R^2$ when removing that predictor from an expanded model?


Thank you however this is actually same as putting a prior on (0,0,0) coordinate point. To give an example I am looking for a nonlinear dependency on global mean, instead of a linear dependency.

@CagdasOzgenc I'm afraid I don't know what you  are talking about. Maybe you can give a clear example of the type of analysis you are looking at?

For example calculate a point using the data and shrink towards it. Not to a predetermined point like (0,0,0).

The bigger issue is shrinkage should still improve MSE after partial order is violated.

@CagdasOzgenc Can you point me to a concrete implementation of a method like that? Otherwise just consider a case where the calculated point is close to (0,0,0) or generally in the "right" direction given the correlations.

Your answer actually gave me an idea. For example James Stein estimator can be used to shrink means to the coordinate (global mean, global mean, global mean).  Global mean is the means of three coordinates. This estimate will not change the partial order. But if we apply this idea to the ridge setting such as $\lambda||\beta - (gb,gb,gb)||_2^2$ it will do the trick you mentioned in your answer. the catch is whether this will improve the MSE or not. If you can tailor your answer towards this it can be interesting.

JS is guaranteed to have lower MSE. But if we introduce the ridge non-linearity do we still get a lower MSE for a particular $\lambda$? There are proofs of optimality for ridge but our case is a little specific, I don't know if those proofs apply here. even if they did does the optimal $\lambda$ yield an estimate where partial order is violated at least in some cases.

Even if we consider a case where we are close to (0,0,0) as you suggest, is the MSE optimal $\lambda$ point after we have a crossover in the ordering of the coordinates (i.e. the right hand side of your chart)? Otherwise our shrinkage approach is useless in a sense.

Not all postestimation shrinkage approaches preserve relative sizes of coefficient estimates. There are three types of shrinkage factor estimation: global, parameterwise, and joint. Only the global shrinkage factor guarantees to preserve relative sizes of coefficient estimates because it coerces proportional changes to all coefficients. Parameterwise shrinkage factor, on the other hand, can change relative sizes of shrunken coefficients by applying different shrinking factors to each coefficient. Joint shrinkage factor maintains relative sizes of shrunken coefficients within a specified set of coefficients.
See the definition by Dunkler D, Sauerbrei W, Heinze G (2016). Global, Parameterwise and Joint Shrinkage Factor Estimation. Journal of Statistical Software. 69(8), 1-19. http://dx.doi.org/10.18637/jss.v069.i08, reviewed by Heinze, G., Wallisch, C., & Dunkler, D. (2018). Variable selection: A review and recommendations for the practicing statistician. Biometrical Journal. Biometrische Zeitschrift, 60(3), 431–449. https://doi.org/10.1002/bimj.201700067. See a tutorial of all these three shrinkage methods at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shrink/vignettes/JSSexample.html.

Although mean estimation can be formulated in a regression setting the focus of these papers are variable selection not mean estimation.

You of course preserve order when you e.g. shrink every estimate by a fixed addition/subtraction or fixed factor (those order preserving operations, like some other operations).
A very obvious case that would not preserve order is the case of a Bayesian prior where there's either

a tighter prior (for whatever reason, maybe we just have more information on some means) despite similarly tight likelihood, or
a tighter likelihood (e.g. because we have more data because some of the multivariate means have missing information, or because observations on one mean are more variable - e.g. because the phenomenon is more variable or measurement of it has more error) despite similar priors, or
the case where two means just have priors that have totally different areas where they have most distributional mass (so they shrink towards a totally different place, but that's kind of the most boring case where it is just totally clear you'd get this), or
any combination of the above.

Options 1 and 2 are illustrated in the plots below. In the first case the datapoints are 15, 14, 16 (in red) vs. 17, 7, 27 (in blue). In the second case the datapoints are 15, 14, 16 (darkred) vs. 17, 16, 18 (black).



Not an "arbitrary prior somewhere" is very different from "no known prior". In empirical Bayes you'd definitely get the second scenario where different means have different amounts/precision in evidence though.
